# snakemake declare temporary files in config

Tags: python, python-3.x, snakemake

Is there any way to declare whether certain files should be temporary or not in the config file? I am working on a pipeline with many output files marked as temporary. For testing purposes, I'd like them not to be temporary. Instead of removing the `temp(...)` for each of the output files and adding that back after my testing, is there a way to specify this in one place either at the top of the snakefile or in the config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use of flag `--notemp` in snakemake command ignores `temp()` declarations and keeps them instead of deleting them.

```
--notemp, --nt  

Ignore temp() declarations. This is useful when running only a part of the workflow, since temp() would lead to deletion of probably needed files by other parts of the workflow.

Default: False
```

[Source](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#BEHAVIOR)